# how should I understand 'seek' and 'count' of dd command?

Tags: boot, partitioning, disk, dd

Please see the dd command and the output below.

```
dd if=/dev/null of=./VirtualDisk.img bs=1M count=1024  
0+0 records in   
0+0 records out   
0 bytes copied, 0.000281296 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

I expected 1024 blocks of size 1MB will be written to the output file. But why is the output file size of VirtualDisk.img 0?

Also, see another example.

```
dd if=/dev/null of=./VirtualDisk.img bs=1M seek=1024
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.000254032 s, 0.0 kB/s
```

According to the manual, is should skip 1024 blocks of size 1MB from the start of output file. But the generated output file size of VirtualDisk.img is 1073741824 (1MB * 1024). I could see the skipped region was filled with zero.

THis is the dd manual : https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dd.1.html
To me, the behavior for `count` and `seek` is different from what the manual says.  How should I absorb this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seek= how far you go ahead in the output file

skip= how far you go ahead in the input file

count= how many segments you copy (can be set via bs=)

say you have 2 16 byte files like so:

```
file1: 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF

file2: 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
```

heres some commands and sample outputs:

```
dd if=file1 of=file2 count=12 bs=1 seek=4
file2: 01 01 01 01 [00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB]


dd if=file1 of=file2 count=12 bs=1 skip=4
file2: [44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF] 01 01 01 01

dd if=file1 of=file2 count=12 bs=1 skip=4 seek=4 count=8
file2: 01 01 01 01 [44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB] 01 01 01 01
```

Comment: One more thing, when I give null file as `of`, and I give `seek` value, the generated file is filled with zero until the seek position. That was my original question. and welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You just created a *sparse* file of that size.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file

That means that an application can read a lot of zeroes from that file, yet it doesn't consume much disk space until an application actually writes data to it.

In this context, the `seek` parameter means "skip n blocks, then begin writing", leaving a "hole" at the start of the file, i.e. there is no disk space (yet) allocated to that part of the file.

Using `/dev/zero` as the input file seems to have the same effect. (Though I admit I hadn't expected that; I would have expected the file to be filled with actual zeroes occupying actual disk space).

Comment: Hi, my observation is, with the `seek` option, the output file size was 1G (1M * 1024) and the content was all zero.(not sparse file).. And the output file with `count` option has file size 0 (no meta data, it's just an empty file). Do you mean output file with `count` option is a sparse file? your answer says otherwise.

Comment: A sparse file can also have **no** disk block allocated.

Comment: I didn't know that. thanks!